# 2 way reverse lights

Tags: reverse-lights

so basically i just got some bright leds for my reverse lights. I want to be able to turn my reverse lights on even when I'm not  in reverse, which would be done by a toggle switch I'll put on my dash but i also want the reverse lights to come on when i put my car in reverse and also i want it to work properly what i mean is i should not have to turn the switch off then put my car in reverse and vise versa .i basically drive at night on my farm and wanna be able to have some light in the rear but i don't want to put some aftermarket lights in my bumper ect. Is this possible and if it is how would it work. Do i need oneway/blocking diodes or relays? You can call this setup a switch back but like with 1 light cause technically in a switchback you switch from white to amber and vise versa but in my case you can say i want 2 way switch in a car. Please don't ask me why i wanna do this, if you have answers i highly appreciate your help Thanks :)

Comment: In some countries, a rear white light that can be manually switched on when the vehicle is moving forward is illegal *for road use.* (The reason being that other road users will assume the white lights are on an approaching vehicle.) Of course that may not apply to the OP's intended use of the lights.

Comment: What make, model, year, transmission type?

Comment: Its a 2000 toyota 4runner  and @alephzero I will only use my little light mod offroad on the farm.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to use your toggle switch to supply the reverse light wire which runs from front to rear - from the reverse light switch.

The supply to the switch needs to be fused whether it is from ignition or permanent supply.

This assumes that the car does not have lots of computer control modules, which may require different options... But as you did not give make, model or year it was a fair assumption...

Edit, you could use a 2 or 3 position switch as so which would avoid the possibility of "back-feeding"...

[image]

Comment: Its a 2000 toyota 4runner so its the most basic electrical system i gotta play with. So basically the wire for the switch will come from ignition with a 20amp inline fuse and after the switch it would go straight to the positive side of the reverse light wire in the back of the suv. My concern was, if i run it like this wouldn't it mess up the cars reverse light circuit with the current going back into the oem wiring for reverse and also it might show the reverse signal light on my dash even if I'm in D(drive). Incase you ask the reverse ler reverse light bulbs I got are 10watt each